# Acumatica Determine which button was clicked (Save or Complete)

Tags: acumatica

[Activity screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWuOQ.png)

How can I determinate which button was clicked in Acumatica on the Activity screen (CR306010)?

I need to determinate on the Acumatica Activity screen which button was clicked: Save button, Save & Close or Complete.

I tried idea to use Acumatica PXContext.Session.SetString.

I overrided CRActivityMaint BLC and markAsCompleted() inside in order to set buttonclicked value for Complete button:

```
public delegate void markAsCompletedDelegate();
[PXOverride]
public void markAsCompleted(markAsCompletedDelegate baseMethod)
{
   baseMethod();
   PXContext.Session.SetString("buttonclicked", "Complete");
}
```

but I can't find a way to set for the same key (buttonclicked)  value "Save" (when save button was clicked) and value "Save & Close" when Save & Close button was clicked.

I need to find a way somehow to set:

PXContext.Session.SetString("buttonclicked", "Save"); - for Save button;
PXContext.Session.SetString("buttonclicked", "Save & Close"); - for Save & Close button;

Is that possible in Acumatica to set it inside of some overeided method like:

```
**Pseudocode:**

public delegate void needToFindSaveDelegate();
[PXOverride]
public void needToFindSave()
{
   baseMethod();
   PXContext.Session.SetString("buttonclicked", "Save");
}

and:

**Pseudocode:**

public delegate void needToFindSave&CloseDelegate();
[PXOverride]
public void needToFindSave&Close()
{
   baseMethod();
   PXContext.Session.SetString("buttonclicked", "Save&Close");
}
```

I would be very thankful for any help how it can be accomplished.

Thanks in advance.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Why do you need to determine that?

Comment: Hi Samvel,
because I have custom Attribute for field TimeBillable in PMTimeActivity DAC (for Activity screen). And the code for this attribute is invoking when I click as Save button as Complete button. I need somehow to know Action (Save or Complete) which invoke code in body of attribute.
Do you have any ideas how it can be implemented?

Comment: Have you tried to write  `RowPersisted` event handler in your attribute?

Comment: Absolutely. I Have RowPersisted (public virtual void RowPersisted(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e)) there but as we both know this event is raising as when you click Save button as when you click Complete button. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that Acumatica add the action name to the `HttpRequest` `Parameters` in the  **__CALLBACKPARAM** parameter. So you can get which action has been called by checking it. You will need to add `System.Web` to your solution for being able to work with HttpContext.

```
string actionName =HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["__CALLBACKPARAM"].Split('|')[0]
```

Below is screenshoot of the value in case of pressing save button on Sales Orders Page:

[image]

And here is case of the `Save and Close` press:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Samvel. This answer gave me especially what I was expecting from the answer. Have a nice day !!!

Comment: If you would have a question according to Acumatica Framework with similar problem feel free to ask me and I will be pleased to help.

Comment: Be warned that this solution depends on implementation detail as __CALLBACKPARAM is not documented. This could be an issue if a product updates changes that feature or when seeking certification of your solution with Acumatica.

Comment: @HB_ACUMATICA yes, it's not a good solution, but on the other hand there is no documented way to this.